# Silverlight 4: Where is the HtmlBrush?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

This is strange. I load the System.Windows.dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50401.0\System.Windows.dll) in the Reflector and do a search for [HtmlBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.htmlbrush%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) but nothing comes up. Anyone got a clue why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HtmlBrush` has been renamed to `WebBrowserBrush`.