# How to display HTML content in Silverlight 5 control

Tags: c#, html, silverlight

I have a `Silverlight` project which is embedded in my Webpage.

The `silverlight` control must display `HTML` content, very basic stuff like

```
 <b> <font> <p> tags
```

However the Web browser control is only available in an out of browser app which mine isnt.

I looked for `HtmlBrush` as other suggested but cant find this control

So how do I add a text content control that can display `HTML` content?

**UPDATE**

I wasnt able to do this with the standard Silverlight restrictions. So what I found was a library that converted HTML,RTF to Silverlight RichText format.

The link I found is [here](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/converting-rtf-to-html/)
Just in case anyone else could benifit from this.

Comment: [where-is-the-htmlbrush](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738828/silverlight-4-where-is-the-htmlbrush) I found this post stating it changed for 4.0

Comment: ok WebBrowserBrus, does that mean its not available for in-browser experience

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of **WebBrowser** Control,

XAML:

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
            <Border Width="300" Height="200" BorderBrush="#000000" >
                <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" />
            </Border>
     </Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser.NavigateToString("<h1>HTML in Silverlight</h1><p>This is some <strong>simple HTML</strong>!</p>");
        }
```

read More here,

[Html inside Silverlight](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/silverlight-4-s-new-html-hosting-support)

For browser inside application,

[Not out of browser - HTML inside Silverlight](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/09/hosting-html-in-silverlight-not-out-of.html)

Comment: Thanks but the web browser is apparently only available in an out of browser use. My SL project runs inside a browser.

Comment: i have modified the andwer, check the link

Comment: OK the post no longer exist

Comment: No bro! It is there, check properly

Comment: Cool I see it now, lloks like this might work. Thanks